# How can I preserve first original value on keyup event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dQ6vZ/22/

I have a case where I have repeating elements with some numeric values.

```
<div class="chars">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <span class="myVal">5</span>
    <span class="pres"> - preserved: 5</span>
</div>

<div class="chars">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <span class="myVal">10</span>
    <span class="pres"> - preserved: 10</span>
</div>
```

On keyup event (when typing text) I am supposed to preserve the very first original value from span element with class myVal but update the value in the same element as I type.

So if the original value was 5, I need to keep 5 while I replace the value visible to the user with a new value.

My beginning looks something like this:

```
var new_value = 0;

$( ".chars" ).keyup(function() {

    var preserved_increment = parseInt($(this).find(".myVal").text());

    var text_length = parseInt($(this).find("textarea").val().length);

    new_value = text_length + preserved_increment;

    $(this).find(".myVal").text( new_value );
    $(this).find(".pres").text( " - not preserved: " + preserved_increment );
});
```

Comment: Do this: <span class="myVal" pres="10">10</span>
in js you can read it with attr("pres")

Comment: You probably want to specify a radix for your `parseInt()` function calls: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use data-* attributes, and then use jQuery's `.data` method to get the value

HTML

```
<div class="chars">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <span class="myVal" data-preserved="5">5</span>
    <span class="pres"> - preserved: 5</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
var preserved_increment = parseInt($(this).find(".myVal").data("preserved"));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dQ6vZ/28/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [data function provided by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) for this task.

I have updated your code to preserve the original value inside the text area. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dQ6vZ/27/)

To access the original value, simply call:

```
    var originalValue = $(this).find(".myVal").data("original")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reference link. That was very helpful.